# Data of places from Fourquare

Tags: android, json, get, foursquare

I need data of places from Fourquare. I tried to use [Venue](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues). But don't have response.

```
      try {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         String getURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4cbd52efd78f46881cf1cc73";     
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
        if (resEntityGet != null) {  
            // do something with the response
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
            Log.i("GET RESPONSE", response);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How to use this?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: No. I want data with id of venue.

Answer (score 0):

You should query your Latitude and Longitude for getting nearest Location. It makes sense.

Change you URL to below to get nearest place :

```
String getURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll="Your Latitude","Longitude"&intent=checkin&limit=50&oauth_token=MVVYZJAO0V4UNTA3YFHGI5YO2YEXIM3TTLW1GO2YZNOZZXER";
```

**ll** - Latitude & Longitude

**oauth_token** - Your Valid Token

**Limit** - As you like nearer to you

Answer (score 0):

Almost every query to the Foursquare API must include a valid OAuth token. In some cases, such as yours, you may use the Client ID and Client Secret that Foursquare gave you after registering your app (but it's a bad idea if you want to distribute your app). After appending the token to the URL, you'll get the JSON answer you're expecting.

You can find an example on getting a OAuth token on Android in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/foursquare/android-oauth-example)